# Combining multiple SPF records that have different "all" modifiers

Tags: dns, spf

I'm inheriting a site that came with multiple SPF records in multiple TXT records (which all of my searching up until this point has informed me is about as invalid as you can get).

Here are the records I'm working with:
Record 1: `v=spf1 include:servers.mcsv.net ?all`
Record 2: `v=spf1 include:zoho.com ~all`

Record 1 appears to be a Mailchimp record. I'm not sure if the client is using Mailchimp or not. Record 2 is obviously from Zoho, but I know for sure the client is using Zoho. Ideally, I'd like to combine these two records into one.

Both records provide a slightly different `all` value. Record 1 gives me `?all`, and Record 2 gives me `~all`. If I understand the syntax correctly, `~all` should be slightly more restrictive than `?all`, and I can have only one `all` value, which must come last in the record.

If they had the exact same `all` value, I could just do something like this:
`v=spf1 include:servers.mcsv.net include:zoho.com ?all`

If I combine the records, I'm not sure which `all` value I should use or why. If I set one record to start with `v=spf2`, I'm not sure the service will verify the record. I've been searching and haven't found any resources that touch on combining multiple SPF records that have different `all` values. What should I do here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An appropriate combination of these two would be:

```
v=spf1 include:servers.mcsv.net include:zoho.com ~all
```

`?all` is essentially useless - it's pretty much equivalent to not having an SPF record at all.

That's not all though - this record looks incomplete. Unless you domain *only* sends from mailchimp and zoho, all other mail will get a softfail response, so if you send "normal" mail from this domain using its own mail server, you probably want to add at least `mx`, and if you send any mail directly from the domain's web site, you would want an `a` mechanism too, giving:

```
v=spf1 mx a include:servers.mcsv.net include:zoho.com ~all
```

DMARC is an important factor, as @lgc_ustc said. If you're *not* using DMARC, I would recommend setting `-all` as your default mechanism to get maximum benefit from SPF, but if you *are* using DMARC, leave it as `~all`. This is because some SPF checkers encountering a `-all` will reject messages immediately, rather than letting them be passed on to the DMARC layer, where a sender can be told what to do with a rejected message.

Comment: This is informative, thank you for answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

> If I set one record to start with v=spf2, I'm not sure the service will verify the record.

There can be only one SPF record on any domain. If more than one SPF record are set, SPF will return PermError. See: [RFC 7208](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-4.5)

Also, all SPF records must start with "v=spf1", everything else is invalid.

`?all` means neutral in SPF. SPF neutral can be interpreted in DMARC as either pass or fail, depending on how you set up DMARC on your email server. This is normally controlled by a flag in your DMARC setup, and it varies across DMARC packages. If you use [OpenDMARC by Trusted Domain](http://www.trusteddomain.org/opendmarc/), SPF neutral is interpreted in DMARC as fail by default.

`~all` means softfail in SPF. SPF softfail is a weak statement that the host is probably not authorized. The domain has not published a stronger, more definitive policy that results in a "fail". This is typically implemented by appending a ~all mechanism to an SPF record. When this mechanism is evaluated, any IP address will cause SPF to return a softfail result.

Like neutral, SPF softfail can be interpreted in DMARC as either pass or fail, depending on how you set up DMARC on your email server. In OpenDMARC, SPF softfail is interpreted in DMARC as fail by default.

Learn more in this post: [Why SPF Authentication Fails: none, neutral, fail(hard fail), soft fail, temperror, and permerror Explained](https://dmarcly.com/blog/why-spf-authentication-fails-none-neutral-fail-hard-fail-soft-fail-temperror-and-permerror-explained)

---

Comment: Oh, interesting. I could swear I came across something that said SPF records can be v=spf1, v=spf2, etc. Thanks for shedding some light on that.

Comment: You might be talking about Sender-ID, which is not SPF.